# typing indicator in chatbot

Tags: botframework, chatbot

Typing indicator for bot framework in nodejs

Hi,

i am working with microsoft bot framework v4, node js, i need to implement typing in chat bot. the bot should respond like(...) as response before sending the original response. 
i have seen the code here [Send a typing indicator in bot-framework v4 using DirectLine and webchat (Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53582445/send-a-typing-indicator-in-bot-framework-v4-using-directline-and-webchat-node-j)

code is working fine in local but when i deploy it to azure, typing(...) is not coming, i can see a delay for 3 secs in response in azure .

my code

```
await step.context.sendActivities([
                                { type: 'typing' },
                                { type: 'delay', value: 3000 },

                            ]);`
```

Thanks
Sanjeev Gautam

Comment: On which channel are you experiencing this behaviour after the deployment to Azure?

Comment: Typing indicator **IS** working, **BUT** you are having delays? In what **Channels** are you experiencing those delays

Comment: @ Mick and @ Marc Asmar, i am using web page as channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help and suggestions. I have changed  **webSocket: true,** in botConnection of chatter.html and solved my purpose. Before it was webSocket: false.

```
 var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
        secret: model.secret,
        token: model.token,
        domain: model.directLineUrl,
        webSocket: true,
        conversationId: getPersistedConversationId(),
        watermark: 0
    });
```

Thanks
Sanjeev Gautam

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this appears to be a bug with Test in Web Chat. The typing indicator, as expected, *should* visibly display. An issue was created in the BotFramework-WebChat repo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2493) reporting the bug.

I would recommend commenting on the issue so the Web Chat developers can fully appreciate any impact.

Hope of help!