# How to enable typingIndicator in bot-framework webchat?

Tags: botframework

I want to implement `Typing indicator` when the bot is sending the response is their features already implemented in Bot framework webchat? if so can you please guide me on what I have to include in my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send a typing indicator in bot-framework v4 using DirectLine and webchat (Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53582445/send-a-typing-indicator-in-bot-framework-v4-using-directline-and-webchat-node-j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webchat is already setup to render typing indicators. You must add typing middleware to your bot code.

- https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/showTypingMiddleware.ts
- https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ShowTypingMiddleware.cs